# Convert a file with json on each line to single json and add values with same keys as comma separated with JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a file `vf.json` that looks like below:

```
{"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1"}
{"ens1f0": "ens1f0v0"}
{"ens1f1": "ens1f1v1"}
{"ens1f1": "ens1f1v0"}
{"ens2f1": "ens2f1v0"}
```

I want to transform it into a single json structure like this:

```
{
    {"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1"},
    {"ens1f0": "ens1f0v0"},
    {"ens1f1": "ens1f1v1"},
    {"ens1f1": "ens1f1v0"}
}
```

I also want to add values with same keys as comma separated inside same key, so that will make above json look this this

```
{
    {"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1, ens1f0v0"},
    {"ens1f1": "ens1f1v1, ens1f1v0"}
}
```

So far, I have only been able to do this

```
# jq -s '.' vf.json
[
  {
    "ens1f0": "ens1f0v1"
  },
  {
    "ens1f0": "ens1f0v0"
  },
  {
    "ens1f1": "ens1f1v1"
  },
  {
    "ens1f1": "ens1f1v0"
  },
  {
    "ens2f1": "ens2f1v0"
  },
  {
    "ens2f0": "ens2f0v0"
  }
]
```

This gives a list of those elements, I do not want a list. I want a json so that i can query it with the key to get the value.

EDIT:

With reduce filters, I am able to merge multiple objects into one:

`jq -s '. | add' vf.json`

```
{
  "ens1f0": "ens1f0v0",
  "ens1f1": "ens1f1v0",
  "ens2f1": "ens2f1v0",
  "ens2f0": "ens2f0v0"
}
```

But I am losing data with this..as there are duplicate keys with differing values. How do I add it like:

```
{
    "ens1f0": "ens1f0v1,ens1f0v0",
    "ens1f1": "ens1f1v1,ens1f1v0",
    "ens2f1": "ens2f1v0"
}
```

Comment: Objects must consists of key/value pairs; `{{...},{...}}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Do you maybe mean `{"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1", "ens1f0": "ens1f0v0", ...}`? That could be queried by key.

Comment: Or not, since some keys are duplicates...

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, this - `{"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1", "ens1f0": "ens1f0v0", ...}` but the issue is still duplicates, so, can those be combined somehow? Like this -> `{"ens1f0": "ens1f0v1,ens1f0v0", "ens1f0": "ens1f1v0,ens1f1v1", ...}`  ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first task:

```
jq -s . vf.json
```

The second task seems somewhat misguided as it would almost certainly be wiser to combine the same-key values into an array, which can be done like so:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; ($in|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] += [$in[$k]] )'  vf.json
```

This solution is, however, easily modified to achieve the string-valued result if that is really what you want:

```
jq -n '
  reduce inputs as $in ({};
    ($in|keys[0]) as $k | .[$k] += [$in[$k]] )
  | map_values(join(","))
' vf.json
```